# Media print ignored when generating png with phantomjs

Tags: css, phantomjs

I'm using `PhantomJS` to create a `png` with the following html and I want my `hideMe` class to be hidden when the `png` is generated. Unfortunately creating a `PDF` hides it, but won't for `jpg` or `png`. How can I hide the following div with the media query print?

```js
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address, output, size;

if (system.args.length < 3 || system.args.length > 5) {
    console.log('Usage: rasterize.js URL filename [paperwidth*paperheight|paperformat] [zoom]');
    console.log('  paper (pdf output) examples: "5in*7.5in", "10cm*20cm", "A4", "Letter"');
    console.log('  image (png/jpg output) examples: "1920px" entire page, window width 1920px');
    console.log('                                   "800px*600px" window, clipped to 800x600');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    address = system.args[1];
    output = system.args[2];
    page.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 600 };
    if (system.args.length > 3 && system.args[2].substr(-4) === ".pdf") {
        size = system.args[3].split('*');
        page.paperSize = size.length === 2 ? { width: size[0], height: size[1], margin: '0px' }
                                           : { format: system.args[3], orientation: 'portrait', margin: '1cm' };
    } else if (system.args.length > 3 && system.args[3].substr(-2) === "px") {
        size = system.args[3].split('*');
        if (size.length === 2) {
            pageWidth = parseInt(size[0], 10);
            pageHeight = parseInt(size[1], 10);
            page.viewportSize = { width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight };
            page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight };
        } else {
            console.log("size:", system.args[3]);
            pageWidth = parseInt(system.args[3], 10);
            pageHeight = parseInt(pageWidth * 3/4, 10); // it's as good an assumption as any
            console.log ("pageHeight:",pageHeight);
            page.viewportSize = { width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight };
        }
    }
    if (system.args.length > 4) {
        page.zoomFactor = system.args[4];
    }

    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to load the address!');
            phantom.exit(1);
        } else {
   page.evaluate(function() {
    document.body.bgColor = 'white';
   });
  
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                page.render(output);
                phantom.exit();
            }, 200);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<html>
 <style type="text/css">
  #test1 {
   height: 250px;
   width: 500px;
   background-color:red;
  }
  
  #test2 {
   height: 250px;
   width: 500px;
   background-color: blue;
  }
  
  @media print {
   .hideMe {
    display: none !important;
   }
  }
  
 </style>
 <body>
  <div id="test1">Test div 1</div>
  <div id="test2">Test div 2</div>
  <div class="hideMe">This should be hidden</div>
 </body>
</html>
```